# JSON tag is ignored when inserting struct/document into mongo (through mgo)

Tags: json, go, mgo

This is what the struct looks like
[image]
This is what the documents look like in Mongo.
[image]

Comment: try `bson:"fieldName"` instead of `json:"fieldName"`

Comment: Don't paste images of text. Copy and paste the text directly.

Comment: @Luke Muller, please accept an answer, or post a comment explaining why you can't accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation of the `mgo` package, you will see the structs there are annotated with `` `bson:"fieldName` `` not `` `json:"fieldName"` ``. You can see an example [here](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#BuildInfo)

The reason for this is that mongo uses the [`bson`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v1/mgo/bson) serialization format instead of `json` to send the structures over the wire. `bson` is very similar to `json` in what it can store, but it is a binary format, and is optimized for use in storage systems like a database.

So update your struct to look like so:

```
type Event struct {
    Id           string     `bson:"id"`
    CreationDate time.Time  `bson:"creationTime"`
    CreatorId    string     `bson:"creatorId"`
    Place        string     `bson:"place"`
    ActivityId   string     `bson:"activityId"`
    Time         time.Time  `bson:"time"`
    Lang         string     `bson:"lang"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use both `json` and `bson` tags at the same time.

```
type Event struct {
    Id           string    `json:"id" bson:"id"`
    CreationDate time.Time `json:"creationTime" bson:"creationTime"`
    CreatorId    string    `json:"creatorId" bson:"creatorId"`
    Place        string    `json:"place" bson:"place"`
    ActivityId   string    `json:"activityId" bson:"activityId"`
    Time         time.Time `json:"time" bson:"time"`
    Lang         string    `json:"lang" bson:"lang"`
}
```